# PHP shell_exec() in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu-10.04, shell-exec

I am using ubuntu with libreOffice. I have installed `unoconv` for convert a `*.odp` file to `*.pdf`. When i run the command `unoconv -f pdf myfile.odp` from terminal then it works very fine. I want to do the same thing with using PHP `shell_exec()` method. So, I wrote the following code:

```
$output = shell_exec('unoconv -f pdf test.odp 2>&1');
echo $output;
```

But it shows the following error:

```
/usr/bin/python: /opt/lampp/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/python) 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/bin/unoconv", line 24, in import uno,
unohelper File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uno.py", line 34, in import pyuno SystemError: dynamic module not initialized properly
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you run `unoconv -f pdf test.odp 2>&1` in your terminal, does it throw the same error?

Comment: Please do $output = shell_exec('env && unoconv -f pdf test.odp 2>&1');
echo $output; and compare to your shell's env

Comment: @EduardLuca no but `unoconv -f pdf test.odp` works well in terminal. and doesn't show anything with `unoconv -f pdf test.odp` in php.

Comment: `2>&1` redirects `stderr` to `stdout`. May be this command produces some errors that are not shown when running without redirection of `stderr`. Furthermore, it is better to use absolute paths when executing commands with exec/shell_exec/etc

Comment: @Timur I did the change as you told but still it shows the same error.

Comment: @Arif And where are you running your PHP script? In terminal? Or using web server like Apache?

Comment: @Timur must be in web server.

Comment: @Arif May be your Apache user does not has access to this library... This my last last version at the moment...

Comment: @Timur The Lampp server has access to this library...Its a dedicated server and we can configure it easily. Do i need to install any other things?

Comment: @Arif did you figure out any workaround for this problem? I also need to call python from PHP but getting the same errors. If you have a solution please help!

Answer (score 1):

its the same error for me as well..  but if we run it with exec() it shows some different error.

Moreover the HTTPD of apache runs as user nobody that is the main issue behind it. if it can run by root user then problem will be solved.